# How to remove the extra space in print python?

Tags: printing

```
 celsius = 45
 fahrenheit = (celsius * 1.8) + 32
 print("{:.2f}".format(fahrenheit),'F')
```

The output of this is ---  113.00 F

How do I remove the space before F, so it will look like this 113.00F.

Answer (score 0):

either do like this:
`print("{:.2f}F".format(fahrenheit))`

or simply use the fstrings:
`print(f"{fahrenheit:.2f}F")`

The space between comming from printing two string then print appends them with a space.you can as well do

```
print("{:.2f}".format(fahrenheit), 'F', sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
celsius = 45
fahrenheit = (celsius * 1.8) + 32
print("{:.2f}F".format(fahrenheit))
```

Just move F into double quotes, you will get 113.00F